# MySQL can't connect - ERROR 2002 (HY000). Please HELP!

Tags: mysql, debian, startup

I was using mysql, trying to add some foreign keys to a database on a Debian server... and all of a sudden I started getting this message:

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)

No matter what I do, I get this message. If I restart mysql, it just spits this crap out a bunch of times.

I have rebooted the server a bunch of times, and it's not going away. I have no idea what I did... I was just changing the schema of a database that has actually been in production for over a year.

I recently changed the domain name of this server, but mysql was working for a few days after this change.

Beyond that, I can't think of anything I did differently.

Please help. I have to get this database back online.

**EDIT:** Joy, mysql corrupted my actual database by trying to add foreign keys into a freaking database. The database is toast.

Good thing I have backups, but this is unreal.

Comment: Where do you get this message? Doing what?

Comment: Doing anything. Use a database, showing tables, starting up the server.... everything.

Comment: what are the permissions of /var/run/mysqld/ and underlying files. What is the user for your web service. Your web service user say 'apache' or 'www-data' should have full access to mysqld.sock

Comment: I am getting this error without even considering apache or anything like that. I am getting this error by simply using 'mysql' on the command line. The permissions for that mysqld folder are "drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql root". When the server is running the permission of the sock file are "srwxrwxrwx  1 mysql mysql"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the database was corrupted. If you're also getting an error like this that defies reason, try showing tables and selecting data out of your basic default databases that comes with mysql just to be sure.

In my case, dropping and adding foreign keys actually destroyed my database, which explains why rebooting the server or restarting mysqld was having no effect.

Answer (score 0):

[This seems to be a useful link](http://corpocrat.com/2008/05/16/fix-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-varlibmysqlmysqlsock/).  It suggests starting mysql daemon, then type mysql.

> /etc/init.d/mysqld start
>
> mysql

If that does not work check the config files for both your mysql client and server to make sure they are pointing to the correct locations.

Comment: that's the problem... my server IS running. Of course I used mysqld start/mysql :(

Comment: Check that the socket the server (mysql**d**) is creating is the same location the client (mysql) is looking for it.

Comment: @Marc B: It is the same location. I found that answer a lot on google... but it didn't help me. This was a working configuration. I've changed nothing :(

Comment: sorry, I was hoping that was the case. Have you verified that your server is running? ps -ef | grep mysql

Comment: if it shows that it is running I would check to make sure that it is set to listen to the correct address and you have access to connect with it (this could be different if your are accessing it from local host or from your new site name).

Comment: this is a long shot but if you check and it is running, accepting connections, and you have the appropriate permission to do it, try shutting it down maybe there is a deadlock and no more connections are available or there may be two instances running.

Comment: @John: Yes, the server is running. How do i make sure that it's set to listen to the connect address and that I have access? Would something like this "change out of the blue"? This is what happened. I want to stress that jdbc and the command line have always been able to connect to mysql for over a year. I was actually connected to the database, doing schema changes... and then it just bombed like this for no good reason. I've also rebooted the server entirely. Nothing is working. I don't get it.

Comment: I actually think my production database is corrupted. I can connect to other databases, but I can't connect when I use the production one

Comment: yeah it sounds like maybe your database  may have been corrupted. when you log into your mysql server does it show up when you list all databases?